# Remove TinyMCE Format Menu Tags

Tags: javascript, formatting, tinymce

I want to remove some of the tags defined in TinyMCe format menu. How can i do this on tinymce initialization

Answer (score 2):

You can use theme_advanced_blockformats variable in init function to define the tags you want.

```
theme_advanced_blockformats : "h2,h3,p",
```

above code will allow only h2,h3 and p tags on format menu.

For more details on tinyMCE configuration you can visit [this Tutorial](http://www.innovativephp.com/blog/2011/05/09/tinymce-text-editor-installation-and-configuration-tutorial-for-cms/rAevmZi-DA&ved=0CA8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHcQZWbxJlbndDqWrI06NzpAZbkXA)

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the modern (tinymce 4.0b1) theme?